# Equivalent of jQuery's $(this) in Ractive.js event proxies

Tags: javascript, jquery, ractivejs

I am reading about Ractive.js event proxies [here](http://learn.ractivejs.org/event-proxies/1).

I now want to replace a click event (currently written in jQuery) with an event proxy in Ractive.js. This is the current code:

```
$('.filter-close').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().hide();
});
```

The HTML bit is easy:

```
<a on-click="closeFilter" class="filter-close">close</a>
```

And I know how to create a proxy in Ractive.js:

```
ractive.on( 'closeFilter', function ( event ) {
  //code here
});
```

If I place an alert in there, it executes correctly on click.

The problem I'm running into is, how do I access the element itself. In the example above, I need to hide the parent of the clicked element. In jQuery I used `$(this)` to find the element. How do I do the same in Ractive?

`this` returns the entire ractive object, `$(this)` throws an error, and fetching the element by ID, I think, defeats the purpose of using Ractive in the first place.

I'm also aware of the possibility to pass an argument along with the event, something like `on-click="closeFilter:{{arg}}"`, but don't know what `arg` should be in this case (or if that is the correct approach at all).

Can someone point me in the right direction here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`event.node` gives access to the DOM element

```
ractive.on( 'activate', function ( event ) {
  // event.node will be the button (will be <button on-click='activate'>Activate!</button>)
});
```

To access the parent node you can do `event.node.parentNode`

If you have jquery on your page then you can easily do `$(event.node.parentNode).hide();`

Answer (score 2):

So, you are after [event.node](http://docs.ractivejs.org/latest/proxy-events) and then access the parent node in Javascript and hide it, like below.

```
ractive.on( 'activate', function ( event ) {
    event.node.parentNode.style.display = 'none';
}
```